# Laravel Passport has no Vue component file

Tags: php, laravel, vue-component, laravel-passport, laravel-8

I recently installed Passport to my Laravel 8 project and took the necessary steps, but when I want to do a front-end quickstart with:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

It displays an error message saying the following.

> Unable to locate publishable resources

Please help? I've scoured the net for answers but have come up short.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Laravel Passport has any publishable tag called `passport-components`

As far as the documentation goes there are three publishable tags

- tag=passport-config to publish configuration file at `config/passport.php`
- tag=passport-migrations to publish migration files for Passport
- tag=passport-views to publish views for authorization approvals

Comment: Yeah the error was on my part I forgot I recently upgraded to version 8 and was still viewing version 7 documentation on the official site. Appreciate the help tho

Comment: First  you have to run this (composer require laravel/ui  ), to install the required view you'd like to use e.g. blade, vue, react etc, the run the command (php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-views). This has worked for me.