# How to solve: Unable to locate publishable resources error (Laravel 8 Passport)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

In Laravel 8, I am trying to publish passport components using the following.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

It gives me this error.

> Unable to locate publishable resources.

Comment: I believe the same question was already answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65364206/laravel-passport-has-no-vue-component-file).

Comment: you may be looking for php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-views

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-views this is working for blade views not vuejs components